# conditional css styles not being applied to content loaded via ajax on ie7

Tags: html, css, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I'm in the process of trying to fix some IE7 issues with Rails app I'm working on.  The issue is that it seems as though CSS styles added from a stylesheet applied with a conditional comment, in HAML using:

```
/[if IE 7]
  = stylesheet_link_tag '/ie7.css'
```

The styles defined in this stylesheet are applied correctly, except to any content loaded in via ajax.  We are using $.ajax to load html content into an existing div.  I've tried using ie8.js and the html5shiv.js to fix this but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just apply the IE7 styles via the HTML Document? Using the following syntax:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Find out more about the Internet Explorer HTML Conditional Comments below.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: i'll try that out, though i was hoping to avoid having to include the stylesheet in the partial, as that would lead to a lot of duplication throughout the application.  i was avoiding that approach for that reason, though it may be the only way to make it work.  thanks!

Comment: @JamesMartin: No problem James. Per your duplication problem. I would assume you would be using some sort of Includes for a website. Check out PHP Includes http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php to address this duplication annoyance.

Comment: just tried it, and it is still not loading respecting the styles.  it's like ie7 is just disregarding the stylesheets after the initial full-page load.

thanks for your help, though.  oh, and this is all in the context of a rails 3.2.x app.

Comment: Are you calling the IE7 specific styles after calling the Original StyleSheet? You must make sure that IE7 styles over ride the default styles by calling the IE7 styles after the default styles have been called.

Comment: I've tried applying them immediately after the original styles, as well as from within the html being loaded in by the ajax call.  neither appears to work.  gotta love ie7 :).

Comment: Do you have a link that I can check out? Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately the site is not publicly viewable so i cannot provide a link.  sorry.  i appreciate the help, though!

Comment: Sorry, James, I wish I could of been more help to you.